# Gatsby app deploy to Netlify issue

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, netlify

Netlify is supposed to be amazing for depoying a gatsby site but having issues such as "Gatsby command not found" when this is the default.
Tried changing to just "BUILD" since this is my package.json script but still nothing... any thoughts?

[image]

Comment: Can you build locally using `gatsby build`?

Comment: And also, would you check your deployment setting? Here is how mine is (with default Gatsby setting) https://i.imgur.com/9w74N7J.png

Comment: Sounds to me like `gatsby` isn't part of your dependencies. Could you make sure it's properly installed inside `package.json`?

Answer (score 1):

The docs at Gatsby instruct you to install the cli globally: `npm install --global gatsby-cli`. This probably results in a missing dependency in production, hence the `gatsby command not found` error.

In short, make sure `gatsby` is part of your dependencies inside `package.json`

Answer (score 0):

Romeo is right, but you have to install gatsby-cli locally (`npm i gatsby-cli`), so that it appears in the package.json file, and saved to Git.

(`npm i -global gatsby-cli` will probably fail, because that will not record the dependency in the package.json file.)

That way, when the netlify build process uses the package.json file to build the package, gatsby-cli is in there, and the "gatsby build" command will be available.